# Defining an own TlsCipherSuite in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ssl, tls1.2

I'm building a WebService using ASP.Net. At the moment the Service is running local and I checked the allowed TLS Versions and Ciphren using NMAP. My Result was this

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers:     
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A    
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A    
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp384r1) - A    
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A    
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C    
|     compressors:     
|       NULL    
|     cipher preference: server    
|     warnings:     
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack    
|_  least strength: C
```

I now want to define my own CipherSet in ASP.Net
I tried using the examples from the Microsoft documentation for kestrel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#listenoptionsprotocols

My Code looks like this:

```
 webBuilder.UseKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
                {
                    kestrelOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
                    {
                        httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;

                        httpsOptions.OnAuthenticate = (connectionContext, authenticationOptions) =>
                        {
                            var ciphers = new List<TlsCipherSuite>()
                            {
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
                                TlsCipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
                            };
                            authenticationOptions.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
                            authenticationOptions.CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(ciphers);
                        };
                    });
                });
```

As soon as I start the WebService I´m getting this Exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: "CipherSuitesPolicy is not supported on this platform."
```

Is there something I need to import to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a solution.
The CipherSuitesPolicy seems to be only available for Linux and MacOS.
For Windows i have to deactivate certain ciphers in the registry

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168" /v Enabled /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168/168" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168/168" /v Enabled /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

This solution works for me. The WebService is now using just strong ciphers